# Error when adding new feature

Tags: pyqgis, spatialite

I wrote a python script for QGIS to create an empty SpatiaLite layer, which the user later can fill with features:

```
import sqlite3


DBdir = r"Test.sqlite"
SPATIALITE = r"path/to/dll"

# Connect to SQlite DB
connection_info = sqlite3.connect(DBdir)
cursor_info = connection_info.cursor()

# SpatiaLite DB will be connected
connection_info.enable_load_extension(True)
cursor_info.execute("SELECT load_extension(?)", [SPATIALITE])

table_name = 'street'
cursor_info.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)")

# Create QgsVectorLayer
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("epsg:25832")
uri = f"{DBdir}|layername=street|geometrytype=Point" 
layer_out = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "street", "spatialite")

# suppress form
formConfig = layer_out.editFormConfig()
formConfig.setSuppress(QgsEditFormConfig.SuppressOn)
layer_out.setEditFormConfig(formConfig)

# set CRS
layer_out.setCrs(crs)

# add layer to project
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.addMapLayer(layer_out)
project.write()
```

The layer also appears in QGIS, however, when I add a new point, it disappears after I safe the changes of the layer and the following warning appears in the OGR tab:

> WARNING Calls to leaveUpdateMode() and enterUpdateMode() do not match

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could find the solution. The problem lies in the creation of the geometry column, which need to be the following:

```
table_name = 'street'
cursor_info.execute(f"CREATE TABLE {table_name} (pk INTEGER primary key)")
cursor_info.execute("SELECT AddGeometryColumn('street', 'geometry', 25832, 'POINT', 2);")
connection_info.commit()
connection_info.close()
```

Hence, the syntax need to be:

> SELECT AddGeometryColumn(table_name, column_name, crs, geometry_type, dimension);

With this, QGIS can connect to the geometry column and write there the created geometry, which wasn't possible in the previous code.